# Naming a file with path separator on Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, base64, sharedpreferences

I am trying to make a settings file for my application using SharedPreferences.
The name of file is encrypted using Base64 like:

> **settings_tNlnyBx1p2mQRgahrEAviA==.xml** (Originally, settings_username.xml)

The tNlnyBx1p2mQRgahrEAviA== depends on users. If users create accounts with other email addresses, the encryption result differs.

However, sometimes the encryption result includes '/' (path separator) and there goes an error on exception. (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) I know the path cannot have '/' but I cannot tell user not to use that email address.

The error looks like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File settings_NGX0Ij2z6L/4xgitGr7apA==.xml contains a path separator
    at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2333)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPrefsFile(ContextImpl.java:400)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:430)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:185)
    at com.heartric.useron.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
    at com.heartric.useron.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
    at com.heartric.useron.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5478) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1827) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

and my code is:

```
 database = getSharedPreferences("settings_NGX0Ij2z6L/4xgitGr7apA==", 0);
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Is it possible to just use SharedPreferences as it is and store each value in it instead of a configuration file?

Comment: @NickB In my application I have to make every settings file for each account to make backup and restore easier, so it is impossible for me

Comment: Why don't you just replace the slash with an underscore?

Comment: @TmTron Could you be more specific?

Comment: String encodedStr = Base64.encodeToString(originalStr.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE);

Comment: You could replace all slashes in the base64-encoded string with underscore characters, before you use it as a file-name. But the note of @Subzero is the better way.